# Manage web references through Configuration Manager/Web Configs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Just started using the Configuration Manager in my asp.net mvc projects to manage connectionStrings between release and debug.

I am wondering how can I do the same thing for a web reference.

Current web.config:

```
<applicationSettings>
  <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="MyProject_SSSWeb_SSS" serializeAs="String">
      <value>http://webservice.example.com/SSS/SSS.asmx</value>
    </setting>
  </MyProject.Properties.Settings>
 </applicationSettings>
```

I'd like to split that out between my Web.Debug.config & Web.Release.config like i currently do with connectionStrings to I can switch between the devel & production web service.

Comment: Transforms like `Web.Debug.config` and `Web.Release.config` simply take the base XML document (in this case, `Web.config`) and *transform* it in some way: change attribute values, add or remove elements, etc. It's just a way of mutating XML, and is therefore pretty agnostic about *what* you can change. So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you add a webreference or service reference to your project using the "Add Service Reference" option in Visual Studio the web.config is automatically updated with binding configuration.

Something like this will be added automatically for a service reference (WCF):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="SSSServiceBinding">
        <security mode="Transport" />
      </binding>
      <binding name="SSSServiceBinding" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://webservice.example.com/SSS/SSS.asmx?wsdl" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSSServiceBinding" contract="SSSServiceContract" name="SSSServiceContract" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Other non-wcf webservices are added in a similar fashion. Using [web.config transformations (xdt)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it is now a breeze to edit the `<client>` section to use different endpoints based on your build profile.